# Pynput cancels non-pynput held inputs

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to implement a straightforward text replacer that is used while other inputs (i.e. rmb) are held down.

Simple example, expectation is that I can hold down "w" and press "a" at some point, whereupon it will type "abc" and continue spamming "w". Interchangeable with holding RMB, for example but holding w is easier to see:

```
from pynput import keyboard



# The key combination to check
combination = keyboard.KeyCode(char = "a")

def execute():
    keyboard.Controller().press('b')
    keyboard.Controller().release('b')
    keyboard.Controller().press('c')
    keyboard.Controller().release('c')

def on_press(key):
    if key == combination:
        execute()

def on_release(key):
    return


listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
listener.join()
```

What happens is after I press the key which triggers the execute() function, any key or input that was being held beforehand is cancelled. Is there a way to resume the held input without letting go of the key and re-pressing it?